# Rigel Wordpress Theme Hover Boxes not working on ipad and galaxy tab

Tags: css, wordpress, hover

You can check my current web here 
I am talking about this section
This section is working working perfectly on laptop but on iPad and galaxy tab this section is ruined.
Also i'm using this custom `CSS` only to make boxes same sizes,

```
.vc-hoverbox-inner { height: 300px; max-height: 300px !important; min-height: auto !important;}
```

[ipad view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lmCz.jpg)

[galaxy tab view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQyl2.jpg)

[wordpress section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXxD8.jpg)

[still](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBdyt.jpg)

[still-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4velz.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i didn't understand your question but here is what i understood.

When the user hovers over the box it flips but in mobile and tab version it doesn't.

The answer is that the mobile and tab doesn't have cursor like laptop. So the user needs to click it.
If your question is other, then please let me know.

Comment: Brother, you can see screenshots that I attached for better understand. on click it is flip but the data text goes out of the boxes.

Comment: i checked, it is problem with padding, consider removing padding of this element.
'.vc-hoverbox-block-inner {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    /* padding: 20px; */
}'

Comment: I have write this code .vc-hoverbox-block-inner { flex-shrink: 0; padding: 20px !important; }

Comment: but the problem is still there

Comment: set padding to 0!important not 20px

Comment: The text is little much better but still goes out of the boxes

Comment: i will check it again. in my case it worked perfectly but let me check it again

Comment: you can check screenshot "still-2"

Comment: you have to define media queries. i can check that the text getting out of the box because the boxes didn't fit the screen. The tab screen can't accommodate all these boxes try to reduce them into three by changing width like width:33%. Also i din't see any margin applied. use margin: 0 auto wherever necessary. Looking forward to hear back from you

Comment: @media (min-width: 768px)
.vc_col-sm-3 {
    width: 33%!important;
}

Comment: bilal if you have bought this theme, you can contact the theme devs. Also, i am creating my own theme which is an open source project and will fit your needs. consider to remain in touch with websiteguider.com until an announcement is made through website.

Comment: Thanks Raashid i think dividing the section 3,3,2 now works you check now.

Comment: Also the only problem is with "Virtualization & Containerization" heading on small screen the heading text cutting last few words.

Comment: I will but my one problem is still there

Comment: tell me what is it

Comment: the only problem is with "Virtualization & Containerization" heading on small screen the heading text cutting last few words.

Comment: also on hover/click goes out of box little much

Comment: try to reduce font size from 26px to 22px

Comment: and on iPad the boxes is now fit but it does not flip on click